# Design solution for handling automatic resource freeing?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, resources

I'm a new, self-taught coder and I've been having issues with my program's design and structure. The basic issue is with the freeing of resources that are provided to me through APIs (for example, OpenGL buffers that must be freed using glDeleteBuffers function, etc.) without breaking the encapsulation of my system. Let me give a basic rundown of my set-up:

First of all, my program uses a large 'facade' class called 'Engine', which contains a few subsystems for graphics rendering, audio streaming, event handling, etc. One of the main ideas behind my design was that each subsystem would be as encapsulated as possible; OpenGL calls would ONLY exist within the graphics renderings system, OpenAL calls in the audio, etc.

I also wanted to be careful about resource allocation and freeing, so instead of creating various assets (images, sounds, etc.) with 'new' in other parts of my program, I set up a few factory methods inside the Engine class that creates objects, registers those objects with the proper subsystem (for example, sending an image object reference to the graphics subsystem where it can be properly buffered/registered to OpenGL), and returns smart pointers to those objects..

```
class Engine     //..simplified for sake of example..//
{
private:
    GraphicsSystem graphicsRenderer;
    AudioSystem audioRenderer;
    //..window, events, etc...//

public:
    //ctors.. dtor.. tons of other methods..//

    std::shared_ptr<Image> createImage( /*filepath, size info, other params*/ );

    /*..both of these call equivalent graphics system functions:*/

    bool registerImage( Image & tempImage );    //allocates and registers texture resources..
    bool deregisterImage( Image & tempImage );  //frees those same resources upon object destruction..
};
```

This is an example of what one of the factory methods might look like..

```
std::shared_ptr<Image> Engine::createImage( /*params*/ )
{
    Image * tempImagePtr = new Image( /*params*/ ); //create..

    registerImage( *tempImagePtr ); //register..

    return std::shared_ptr<Image>( tempImagePtr ); //return..
}
```

But here's the main issue that I'm having: I'm finding it hard to free the resources that are allocated using the registerImage function! I'd like to make the code work so that the client is only responsible for retrieving the asset objects from the Engine, the details of resource acquisition and management being abstracted away and handled automatically when the asset objects are destructed..

Here are a few options that I've tried/considered:

- **Have the clients (the users of the Engine class) be responsible for calling the proper deregistration functions before the objects are deleted.** This object is pretty simple to code up front, but really kind of sucks and eliminates the points of using RAII style object creation via factory methods. This doesn't help me realize my goal of allowing the client to simple 'get an asset and forget about it'.
- **Pass a reference to the entire Engine's single instance to each asset class, and allow the asset class to use that reference to call the deregistration function inside its destructor.** This is a solution I tried before as a little 'hack' to just make sure that I had proper automatic resource cleanup working right. It ~worked~ but I didn't like the idea of giving the assets access to all of the engine calls; it seemed overboard to give each asset that kind of access when all they needed was the ability to register/deregister themselves with the Engine!
- I tried to 'clean up my code' and remedy that situation by instead **passing pointers to the proper registration and deregistration functions to the asset objects.** This way, the objects could register themselves upon construction, and deregister themselves upon destruction. It seemed like a good plan, until I tried it.. So far, I've had an extremely hard time passing the Engine's non-stactic methods to the asset objects via the asset factory methods! The C++ syntax is a confusing mess, I have no experience with function pointers (let alone handing out pointers to non-static methods), and it's become so frustrating that I'm considering going back to the sloppy, abstraction-breaking tactic of passing a reference to the entire Engine instance! I've tried using the method name, I've tried adding a '&' before the method name, adding a 'this.' keyword before the method name, etc.

Here's what one of my Image asset constructors looked like:

```
Image( std::string filepath , 
       void (*ptrRegFunc)(unsigned int * tempTextureID, const sf::Image * const tempSourceImage) , 
       void (*ptrDeregFunc)(unsigned int * tempTextureID) );
```

The Image class contained two pointers of the same type, and it seemed fine at first until I tried to pass the pointers...

```
std::shared_ptr<Image> Engine::createImage( std::string filePath )
{
    Image * tempImagePtr = new Image( filePath, &registerImage, &deregisterImage ); //create and send func ptrs..

    return std::shared_ptr<Image>( tempImagePtr ); //return..
}
```

Of course, that didn't compile and I understand why: it's not clear which Engine object/instance is being referred to. But I've looked it up and tried all these different C++ syntax styles;

```
&(this->registerImage)

&((*this).registerImage)
```

Nothing has worked, and the syntax is so horrible that it almost doesn't seem worth the trouble!

But now I feel like I'm back at square one again; so I've been looking at other possibilities. In my head, the idea seems really simple: **I just want to give each Asset object the ability to register and deregister itself with the Engine object.**

Is there a better/simpler way of achieving my goal without giving each asset access to the entire Engine class interface? I've read a little bit about the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern), which sounds like it might be kind of what I'm looking for, but I'm not sure exactly how to go about implementing that pattern, or if it's really what I need. Of course, I've also come across the concept of [Function Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object).. *Would either of those provide a solution to my issue?*

Anyway, thanks for baring with me on this, I'm still just learning and I know this is probably simple stuff for many of you out there. If there is anything else I can explain about what I want or what my current system is using, please let me know and I'll update a.s.a.p.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of info in the question, and I'm not sure I've understood all of it correctly, but I think  the principle of using a `shared_ptr` to handle RAII in this case sounds good. If I've read it right, the problem is that you want to call `Engine::deregisterImage()` when the last `Image` reference is released, right?

Have you tried using a custom deleter for your `shared_ptr`s? If you want to call `Engine::deregisterImage()` just before the `Image` is destroyed, then you'd need some way of binding the `Engine` instance to the shared pointer. There are quite a few ways to do this (lambdas, `std::bind`), but using a functor is quite easy:

```
struct ImageDeleter
{
    Engine& engine;
    explicit ImageDeleter(Engine& e) : engine(e) {}

    void operator() (Image* img) {
        engine.deregisterImage(*img);
        delete img;
    }
};
```

then in your `Engine::createImage()` method, you'd register the deleter in the `shared_ptr` constructor:

```
return shared_ptr<Image>(tempImagePtr, ImageDeleter(*this));
```

Now, when the last reference is released, the `shared_ptr` will call `ImageDeleter::operator()`, and it should all work. This requires that your `Engine` instance outlives all the images that it creates (otherwise you'll be left with a dangling reference), but I'd imagine that would be the case anyway.

Comment: Awesome! I haven't implemented this yet, but it sounds like exactly what I needed. I didn't realize that I could set a deleter function in my shared pointers! I appreciate the help and I'll try the functor out. Thanks a lot Tristan!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit high level but it looks like that's the stage you're at in your design.

For some reason, I am thinking that you may benefit from having a class dedicated to just resource management. This class would handle creation and freeing of resources, it could also provide a way to reuse resource, something like a resource pool.